# TapGestureRecognizer doesnt work when tapping label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a label tappable. But when I try to tap on the label. Nothing is happening. I doesn't call the command.

When I debug it, it never calls the command I have setup.

From ViewModel:

```
public ICommand TappedDateCommand => new Command<int>(ChangeToTappedDate);

private void ChangeToTappedDate(int position)
{
    Position = position;
    PositionChanged(position);
    OnPropertyChanged("Position");
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Label ...">
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding TappedDateCommand}" CommandParameter="0" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using String instead of int.

```
public ICommand TappedDateCommand => new Command<string>(ChangeToTappedDate);

private void ChangeToTappedDate(string position)
{
    Position = Convert.ToInt32(position);
    PositionChanged(position);
    OnPropertyChanged("Position");
}
```

Comment: Can you add the entire Xaml file and the code behind as well ?

Answer (score 0):

About binding command for lanel TapGestureRecognizer, I do one sample that you can take a look:

Firstly, changing the commandhandler to accept parameter and changing the method to accept the commandparameter.

```
 public class RelayCommand1 : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then use the code:

```
 <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding command1}"
                    CommandParameter="55"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>

public partial class Page20 : ContentPage
{
    public RelayCommand1 command1 { get; set; }

    public Page20 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        command1 = new RelayCommand1(obj => ChangeToTappedDate((string)obj));

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public void ChangeToTappedDate(string position)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(position);
        Console.WriteLine("the position is {0}",value);
    }

}
```